# Smart Contract Balance = 0

Tags: truffle, dapps, cpp-ethereum

Ok, I am pretty new to developing contracts, and I did so by using dAPP and truffle. But when adding it to the chain, it says there is no balance to the contract. How can I add tokens to be bought? https://etherscan.io/address/0x8f8a3c51b1eaaefe9052fc86cff57971b11dde45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a contract is created, the constructor function is called to initiate the contract.

Here is the constructor function for your contract:

```
constructor (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
}
```

You can see that this constructor function expects an input of `_initiatalSupply` to define the initial token balance of the contract.

You will need to create a new contract, and make sure to send in a value to be used during contract creation for the constructor function.

Comment: I forgot to add this line: uint256 _totalSupply = 100000000; is that correct?

Comment: @ArnfinnIngebrigtsen No. When you created the contract, you should have supplied the number of tokens you wanted to create to the constructor.